# Styling mat-select when on hover - Angular Material

Tags: css, angular

I have a mat-select, but I'm having trouble changing the color of the value in each mat-option from black to white on hover. I can change them all by using

```
.mat-option {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  color: black !important;
}
```

but it changes the one's that aren't hovering to white too, which I don't want.
How can I change it to white only onhover? Non hovered items would be black

```
     <mat-form-field id="filter" appearance="outline" class="formFields">
        <mat-select [(value)]="selected">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let number of quantity" [value]="number">{{number}}</mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kcmxnv?file=src/app/select.component.css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All CSS changes either you need to make them in the "root" css or use ng-deep  like

```
::ng-deep{
     .mat-option-text:hover:not(.mat-option-disabled) {
      background: #3071a9 !important;
      color: white;
    }

 .mat-option:hover {
      background: red !important;
      color: green !important;
    }
}
```

Since here you are changing a standard control my recommendation is make this change in your styles.css or based css.

**update**
Please node you I think what you want to modify is the `mat-option-text:hover`

**[Online Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7vysb8?file=src/styles.scss)**

Comment: I added your code to styles.css and also tried it within component css, but on ```hover``` still outputs black text instead of white text.

Comment: Works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your stackblitz, there are 2 points you should change:

```
.mat-option:hover:not(.mat-option-disabled) {
  background: #3071a9 !important;
  color: white;
}
```

You should remove the `!important` here.

```
.mat-option:hover {
  background: red !important;
  color: green !important;
}
```

And use this to display your style on hover, the main point is `:hover`.